# Get error on insert date from code sqlite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, datetime

I'm trying to insert this string `2021-02-22T16:11` into sqlite database. I use `VARCHAR(20)` to store this this string. When I execute sql query from SQLite studio everything is fine.
But when I run the same code from my ASP Net Core app, it throws an error:

> code = Error (1), message = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x800007BF):
> SQL logic error unrecognized token: "22T16"

I've tried different data types for this column (TEXT, STRING, DATETIME), but nothing works. Can't understand why it can't insert string even into VARCHAR column.

The function that invokes insert query:

```
public async Task<int> AssignTaskToUser(SaveTaskRequest req, int userId)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")))
            {
                long nextInvokeUnix = ((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.Parse(req.NextInvoke)).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
                long intervalUnix = ((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.Parse(req.TimeInterval)).ToUnixTimeSeconds() +
                    (3600 * 24) * req.DaysInterval;
                connection.Open();
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand();
                command.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO UserTasks " +
                    $"(Name, UserId, TaskId, NextInvokeString, NextInvokeUnix, DaysInterval, TimeInterval, IntervalUnix)" +
                    $"VALUES ({req.Name}, {userId}, {req.TaskId}, {req.NextInvoke}, {nextInvokeUnix}, {req.DaysInterval}, {req.TimeInterval}, {intervalUnix});" +
                    $"{getLastIdRequest}";
                command.Connection = connection;
                long userTaskId = (long)(await command.ExecuteScalarAsync());

                foreach (var param in req.parameters)
                {
                    command.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO UserTaskParameters " +
                       $"(UserTaskId, PrameterId, Value)" +
                       $"VALUES ({userTaskId}, {param.ParameterId}, {param.Value});";
                    await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
                }

                return await GetChangesAsync(connection);
            }
        }
```

Table create script

```
CREATE TABLE UserTasks(
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    UserId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    TaskId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NextInvokeString VARCHAR(20),
    NextInvokeUnix INTEGER,
    DaysInterval INTEGER,
    TimeInterval VARCHAR(6),
    IntervalUnix INTEGER,
     FOREIGN KEY (UserId)
         REFERENCES Users (Id),
     FOREIGN KEY (TaskID)
         REFERENCES APITasks (Id)
);
```

Comment: you need to provide more information , paste here you whole code (sql & asp)

Comment: @eshirvana added. Also, if I hardcode this string "2021-02-22T16:11" into the query, the error shows up on ":11"

Comment: What parameter are you trying insert? You have 5 datetime parameters.

Comment: @Sergey req.NextInvoke. It contains date and time in this format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM. Replacing T with any other character or space mkes nothing.

Comment: Could you show your database table create script and req.NextInvoke - what type and value.

Comment: @Sergey updated the questeion with table scipt. req,Value is astring. In function it takes value 2021-02-22T16:11 or any other date and time I choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use this instead

```
2021-02-22T16:11:59 

//or 

2021-02-22T16:11:00
```

and maybe you can try this too:

```
 $"VALUES ( '{req.Name}', {userId}, {req.TaskId}, '{req.NextInvoke}', {nextInvokeUnix}, ...
```

Comment: It makes some changes. If i hardcode date time with seconds into query it works fine, but if I append ":00" to req.NextInvoke, it throws absolutely the same error.

Comment: It actialy worked. I have forgotten about quotation marks on inserting strings.

Comment: And you can try now to use DateTime with new format like 2021-02-22T16:11:00